# Converting SAS script in R and create a loop

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, sas

I have to translate my scripts in SAS to R, but I don't have so much experience in R and I'm struggling to find a solution.

Here's my SAS code:

```
%macro pluto(num);
    proc delete data=machine_tot; run;

    %do i=1 %to &num.;

        data tot;
            set campione(where=(month_1 >= &i.));

            month_2 = &i.;

            if (&i.-month_3) <= 0 then 
               w = 1;
            if (&i.-month_3) > 0 and (&i.-month_3) < 1 then 
               w = (1-(&i.-month_3));
            if (&i.-month_3) >=1 then 
               w = 0; 
        run;

        proc freq data = campione noprint;
            tables month_2 /out=output;
            weight w;  
        run;

        data cars;
            set val(keep=month_2 COUNT);
            cars_eq=floor(count);
            drop count;
        run;

        proc append data=cars out=machine_tot; run;
    %end;
%mend;

%pluto(&tot.);
```

Basically where month_1 >=1, then month_2 should be 1, and the value of the difference between 1 and month_3 should lead to the classification of w. Then some tables should be produced, and the procedure repeated with values of i from 1 to 24. In the end the results are bound together with append.

I understood that I have to build a loop in R, but so far I could just write the code to do the first step (ideally I should iterate this step for i from 1 to 24).

```
 tot <- campione %>% 
  filter(month_1 >= i)

tot <- tot %>% 
  mutate(month_2 = i)

tot <- tot %>% 
    mutate(diff = as.numeric(i - month_3))

tot <- tot %>% 
  mutate(w = case_when(
    diff <= 0 ~ 1, 
    (diff >0) & (diff < 1) ~ 1-diff, 
    diff >= 1 ~ 0)
  )

val <- tot %>% 
  group_by(month_3) %>% 
  summarise(COUNT = sum(w))

cars <- val %>% 
  group_by(month_2) %>% 
  summarise(floor(COUNT))
```

Any suggestion on how build the loop would be highly appreciated!

**EDIT**

I edit the question trying explain better what I expect the loop does (I'm neither English native speaker nor R expert, so I hope it will be clear enough). I have a df like the following:

```
month_1    month_3    id
1          2.3         1
5          6.6         2
7          7.65        3 
9          8.01        4
24         23.9        5
24         23.97       6
24         23.61       7
24         23.87       8
13         13.07       9
```

I want to take into consideration a loop where i <- 1:24 and to do as follows:

1. group month_1 so that I can count with the first loop all data with month_1 >=i  (with the first loop it would be month_1 >=1, with the    second loop all data with month_1 >= 2 etc)
2. create the variable month_2 and assign to it the correspondent loop value (where month_1 >=i then month_2 = i, i.e. where month_1>=1 then month_2 = 1 , where month_1 >=2 then month_2 = 2 etc)
3. create the variable w so that if i - month_3 < 0 w should be 1, if  i - month_3 > 0 and < 1 w should be (1-(i-month_3), if i - month_3 >= 1 w should be 0.
4. group by month_3 and sum w
5. group by month_2 and sum w
6. start again the loop with next value until i = 24

So, for example, for i = 24 there are 4 rows with month_1 >=24; month_2 should be = 24; w are calculated as follows:

- id 5 ->(24 - 23.90) = 0.10. 0.10 is > 0 and < 1, so w 1-0.10 = 0.90
- id 6 -> 0.97
- id 7 -> 0.61
- id 8 -> 0.87
- group by month_3 and sum -> month_2    sum(w)
                            24          3.35
- group by month_2 and sum -> month_2     floor(sum(w))
                            24           3

Hope it is more clear...

Comment: You shouldn't do line to line conversion. You're better off showing what you have as a starting point and what you want so that the logic can be optimized for R.

Comment: Show desired output which usually better illustrates than words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R tends to work best in vectorization so the easiest way I see to go about this is to simply add a column of i's to your data. Using `expand.grid` will create and all-by-all tibble (data frame) where tot is repeated for each i.

It's still unclear how you want your grouping and such to work, but this should get you close to what you desire:

```
    library(tidyverse)
tot = 
tribble(
  ~month_1,    ~month_3,    ~id,
1,          2.3,         1,
5,          6.6,         2,
7,          7.65,        3, 
9,          8.01,        4,
24,         23.9,        5,
24,         23.97,       6,
24,         23.61,       7,
24,         23.87,       8,
13,         13.07,       9) 

expand_grid(i = seq(1,24) %>% as.numeric, tot) %>% 
  mutate(
    month_2 = case_when(
      month_1 >= i ~ i,
      TRUE ~ NA_real_
      ),
    diff = i - month_3,
    w = case_when(
      diff <= 0 ~ 1, 
      (diff >0) & (diff < 1) ~ 1-diff, 
      diff >= 1 ~ 0)
  ) %>% 
  group_by(i,month_3) %>% 
  mutate(COUNT = sum(w)) %>% 
  ungroup %>% 
  group_by(i,month_2) %>% 
  mutate(cars = floor(sum(w)))
```

Once you summarize, it removes the rest of the columns so grouping by month_2 won't be possible. If you want to group by both to get the floor of the sum of w for each i, that would work too, just add month_2 in the group_by like `group_by(i,month_2,month_3) %>% summarize(cars = floor(sum(w))`.

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to run your example but even if I have tidyr installed expand_grid doesn't exist, did you mean this function or base expand.grid?

Comment: Are you running the newest version of the tidyverse? It was released in September and since you're just learning R now, I'd go ahead and switch over, especially since most of the new answers I see on StackOverlow use the newest version. Otherwise, you can use something along the lines of `tot %>% mutate( id = list(rep(seq(1,24), length(tot)) %>% sort) ) %>% unnest` instead of the `expand_grid`.

Comment: I thought I was using the newest version of tidyverse, but thanks to your hints I found out that my tidyr version is still 0.8.3 and I'm trying to update it (not working at the time but I'll try also your second suggestion, thank you!)

Comment: Sounds good. Have you tried the suggestions here https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/ ? Also, I made an error above. It should be `tot %>% mutate( id = rep(list(seq(1,24)), length(tot)) %>% sort) ) %>% unnest` so you get multiple lists you can unnest with the old version rather than one big list. :)

Comment: Hi, I got it! tidyverse 1.0.0 installed and 1st suggestion run, it works! Thank you so much